# I get the follow LOG Error in XAMPP, How do I fix this

Tags: xampp

I get this error code shown, below how to I fix this,if not fixed I need to copy my coding that is in the htp folder and saved them in a different file, and reinstall it again.

```
2023-02-08  8:52:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2023-02-08  8:52:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    2023-02-08  8:52:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
    2023-02-08  8:52:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    2023-02-08  8:52:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
    2023-02-08  8:52:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
    2023-02-08  8:52:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2023-02-08  8:52:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT at 80837091 between the checkpoint 80837091 and the end 80837082.
    2023-02-08  8:52:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
    2023-02-08  8:52:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
    2023-02-08  8:52:14 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
    2023-02-08  8:52:14 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
    2023-02-08  8:52:14 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    2023-02-08  8:52:14 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
    2023-02-08  8:52:14 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163445/innodb-ignoring-the-redo-log-due-to-missing-mlog-checkpoint

Check the part about the location of the log fil for XAMPP, and follow the instructions. Seems like you had a bad shutdown or something similar since the log file is not up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got another MySQL/MariaDB Server running already?
What is the full contents of your XAMPP control panel log?

Comment: the XAMPP is the only sql server that I run

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open Xampp Control Panel
[Xampp Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Esjp.png)
Step 2: Click on Config -> Click on Service and Port Settings
[Click Configure Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22G78.png)
Step 3: Click on MySQL Tab and change port to 3307 (Note: any other port which is free in your system)
Step 4: Click on Save -> Save.
[Save Service Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPvUY.png)
Step 5: Restart your Xampp Control Panel